# Use of linux commands in Jenkins in windows shell

Tags: c, linux, unit-testing, jenkins

In the **build step** section of the project configuration pane I have the possibility to **execute a windows batch command**.

Is there any way to use this to execute linux commands? Is there any other way?

Comment: Rephrased to be more clear.

Comment: You should be more clear in what you're trying to achieve. E.g. why do you need to execute linux commands or why you can't deploy jenkins on a linux (virtual) machine.

Comment: I would like to execute linux commands in windows shell of Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

You can run scripts in Cygwin:

https://www.cygwin.com/

Like the following:

C:\cygwin\bin\bash mysript.sh

The purpose of Cygwin is to make porting unix-based applications to Windows much easier, by emulating the POSIX layer through the cygwin1.dll

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent build step for Linux is "Execute shell". Of course the job needs to execute on a Linux machine for it to work.

If you want to execute Linux commands on a Windows slave, then use Cygwin or MinGW as others have suggested.

Comment: Yes,I have tried that but the cygwin plugin of Jenkins is not serving my purpose.